# fill an array with exponential of base 2 using recursion

Tags: c#

I'm trying to fill an array with exponents of base two. For example when `n` is `4` the function should return an array like this:

```
1,2,4,8
```

That is, array of size 4 with these elements using recursion.
`n` is the parameter and the array is the output.

How can I do this?

Comment: Okay... so please show us what you've already done, and where you're stuck.

Comment: That should be a typical algorithm that you can find anywhere. Search for DP (Dynamic Programming) and you will find your answer. (you will have a loop with a T[i] = 2*T[i-1]

Comment: But doing `<br>` at the end of the array might cause a problem .... 

Comment: No need to use recursion.  Simple for loop will do.

Comment: @jdweng I suspect homework. Another example of senseless "use recursion just to learn recursion no matter how stupid it would be to actually do this recursively" assignments...

Comment: but recursion is fun. Crashing the computer recursively is fun. Posting a stack overflow question on StackOverflow is ironically fun-ny.

Comment: it's part of a bigger problem.i've been searching months for the answer with no resolve because it's not popular but learning it could help with taking recursion to a hole new level. the full problem is stated below as a comment in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO Amir. This sounds like a homework but I'll do it for you anyway ;)

```
private List<int> GetPowersOfTwo(int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
        return new List<int>();
    
    var list = GetPowersOfTwo(n - 1);
    list.Add((int)Math.Pow(2, n));
    return list;
}
```

Comment: What if I pass in -1?

Comment: Based on your profile I guess you already know and I have no idea why would you ask but, you'll get an empty list which in my mind is a good outcome.

Comment: `GetPowersOfTwo(4);` returns a list of 5 items (`1,2,4,8,16`), So Amir can still do some homework.

Comment: Nice observation @Luuk. I'll not fix this then. I can use some homework too‍♂️

Comment: @Idle_Mind I don't understand... https://dotnetfiddle.net/QfgoxK

Comment: Emad, I'm so sorry. I mis-read the code. It does not get stuck in an infinite loop.  I'll drink some more coffee and wake up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. to be fair this was 5 terms ago and it's a part of a bigger and comlex problem. i used an array implementation but it seem a list works perfictly.

Comment: the more complex problem is: make a function that takes one parameter, n then ,k = 2 ^ n. make an array that looks like this: for n = 4, k is 16 the length of the array is k - 1; 1,2,1,4,1,2,1,8,1,2,1,4,1,2,1. is goes as followed : insert k in the middle of the array, then insert k / 2 in left and right sub arrays the do it all again. very tricky.

Comment: it's like a new recursive mergesort. only more frustrating.